# Eloquent relation without model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Imagine we have two tables:

```
products                product_langs
==============          ==============
   id                      id_product
   name                    lang
                           description
```

Now I want to link these two tables together like:

```
return $product->hasOne('App/ProductLang')
  ->where('id_product', '=', 'id')
  ->where('lang', '=', $lang);
```

Is there an *out of the box* possibility to do this without having the Model `App/ProductLang`?

Comment: Use the Query Builder

Comment: I removed tags from your title, added syntax highlighting for your php code, improved formatting and grammar.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing up relationship definition and building query in here.

If you do not want to define another model then forget about hasOne() and use query builder with join like described here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#joins